# Output cache expire causes sudden increase in WebApi requests (MVC5/webapi2)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, performance, caching

I'm serving pages using MVC5 and getting data from WebApi services. The MVC5 app makes around 60 requests to the WebApi initial page load to get all the data, I'm using OutputCache on the MVC5 side.

This works until the cache expires. When the Output cache expires new calls to the API are triggered, since theres a lot of people using the site the first request won't finish before subsequent requests are made. This means that suddenly our data service has to cope with a huge load. Say that a 100 new visitors come in then the backend receives approximately 6000 requests, of which most include database calls and some requests to other services. Response times get longer and eventually the WebApi tier crashes.

Are there any methods I can apply to cope with this sudden increase in requests? I've considered adding another layer of caching on the WebApi side but would like to know if theres more that can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My two cents here will be suggesting you that, maybe, it's the time to implement a second-level cache mechanism.

Instead of delegating everything to the ASP.NET output cache, you should have cached data in a neutral layer between your front-end and Web API backend which may be updated overtime and asynchronously. That is, users won't get the performance impact of refreshing the whole cache.

If you want to learn more about this topic, s[ome question was thrown in Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-overflow-use-caching-and-if-so-how/69172#69172) and a developer from StackExchange was proud to share with everyone how they implemented caching (either L1 and L2 cache).

Answer (score 0):

I think a sliding expiry cache could help. But I think you'll need to either go third party or create your own attribute for that.

Maybe this can help some:

[Asp.net Mvc OutputCache attribute and sliding expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577160/asp-net-mvc-outputcache-attribute-and-sliding-expiration)